# Retrieve all inputs values from a form AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a massive form with more or less 80 / 90 inputs.

**My main problem is** How can I pass all those inputs belonging to unique form in an ajax request without map the inputs manually into a object?

I know that with jquery you can use `serialize()` function selecting the form. Is there any helper function in angular to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're not using `ng-model` in your forms. Can you post the of the html/js you've got so far? Perhaps only showing a couple of the inputs though...

Comment: Yes, u need to use ng-model in each input, like person.name, person.address, person.secondname, ..... And on submit you just send object 'person' (which will automatically transformed to json).

Comment: Oh, That's correct I'm currently using `ng-model` to my inputs but I didn't think to pass the scope object to get all values! :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as Michal's comment suggested, it doesn't look like you are using `ng-model`.

Angular's jqLite doesn't support `serialize()` since with Angular one would typically build a ViewModel that would then be bound to a form.

But, if you are out of luck, you could add jQuery.js to get the `serialize()` support and create a simple directive - `serializer` - that would act on a form.

```
app.directive("serializer", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      onSubmit: "&serializer"
    },
    link: function(scope, element){
      // assuming for brevity that directive is defined on <form>

      var form = element;

      form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var serializedData = form.serialize();

        scope.onSubmit({data: serializedData});
      });

    }
  };
});
```

And use it as follows:

```
<form serializer="submit(data)">
  <input name="foo">
  <input name="bar">
  <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.submit = function(data){
   console.log(data);
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lyhlVq4gYH9CpvtAlcyw?p=preview)

**EDIT:**

If you are using `ng-model` and in fact have a proper ViewModel, then this is the "Angular way" and so, you should have some object that is bound to the form inputs - you should just submit that.

```
<form name="foo" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
  <input ng-model="fooObject.a">
  <input ng-model="fooObject.b">
  ...
</form>

$scope.fooObject = {};
$scope.onSubmit = function(){
   $http.post("url/to/server", {data: $scope.fooObject})
     .success(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using `ng-model` in my inputs but I didn't think about that it generate the object with all the values. Thanks! Can you please add a little snippet on how you achieve that with the ng-model just to accept your question as correct :)