# How to pass multiple textbox fields to angular js as array

Tags: php, angularjs, post

Below is Controller:

app.controller("DemoController", function ($scope, $http) {

```
$scope.Save = function () { 

    var Details = [];
    Details = $scope.UserForm.AllFields;
    $http.post(
            "api/Add.php",
            {'DemoDetails':$scope.Details}
    ).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // Store response data
        alert(response.data);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert(response.data);
    });
};
```

});

Below is HTML form:

```
`<form method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="username" required="">
<input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" required="">
<input type="submit" name="login" ng-click="Save()" value="login"></label> 
</div>
</form>`;
```

Below is php script:

```
 `<?php 
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata)){

 $request  = json_decode($postdata); 

 $username  = $request->username;
 $password  = $request->password;

 }`;
```

and save to datatabse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to serialize your form like that:

```
var serializedData = UserForm.serialize();
scope.onSubmit({data: serializedData});
```

Before to go further, please take a look on that directive, it is a sharp and fancy way to do what you are trying to do by using directive. [Retrieve all inputs values from a form AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984808/retrieve-all-inputs-values-from-a-form-angularjs)